# Swift, how to add X number of views with constraints dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am developing a swift application which will fit 10 items on the screen. If I wanted to do this on a screen that would not change size i.e. the user doesn't change orientation or an iPad user does not use split screen, I would be able to detect the width by doing `let size = bounds.width/19`.

The problem is as the screen size is dynamic so therefor I need to do it with constraints. I would not like to use UICollectionView as that is too heavy and would also not like to use UIStackView if possible as I don't think it supports aspect ratio which I need for circles. I am trying to use UIViews.

**Edit:**
This is how I want them to look. This will be about 50 high and other information will be underneath.

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular order for the views? Can you add an image showing how they should look?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Done!

Comment: Why don't you want to use `UIStackView`?

Comment: @robmayoff I forgot to mention that its because I'm not sure if I could use aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIStackView` is the right tool for this job. In the future, I recommend more rigorously defining what you *want* to happen first, then dive into the documentation.

```
let sv = UIStackView()
sv.spacing = 10
// this means each arranged subview will take up the same amount of space
sv.distribution = .fillEqually 

for _ in 0..<50 { 
    // omitting the rounded corners or any other styling because
    // it's not the point of this question
    let subview = UIView()
    // The stack view will determine the width based on the screen size
    // we just need to say that height == width
    subview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    sv.addArrangedSubview(subview)
}

// add your stackview to your view hierarchy and constrain it
```

Comment: I agree with Connor. This seems like a job for UIStackView. It makes creating an evenly spaced group of views clean and easy.